# Metafunction as member function parameter

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Currently my code has this form:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
private:
  T data;
public:
  void apply_process(A<T> obj, std::function<T(A<T>&)> process) {
    data = process(obj);
  }
  // ... 
};
```

This works with runtime lambdas; yet, while `obj` will be only known on runtime,`process` will be known at compile time. Can I rewrite this somehow so that `process` is a metafunction to be passed as a compile-time parameter? A C++14 solution is preferable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What do you want to do that isn't possible with the current version?

Comment: If you intend pass `process` as template arguments, it's possible only starting from C++20, as far I know.

Comment: @user17732522 I want a more optimised version actually - since process will be certainly known at compilation time, why pay for the overhead ?

Comment: @MarinosK Then use a template parameter instead of `std::function`, as shown in the answer already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you want, but by combining up the keywords you are throwing, I think you want this:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
private:
  T data;
public:
  template<class UnaryFunction>
  void apply_process(A<T> obj, UnaryFunction process) {
    data = process(obj);
  }
  // ... 
};
```

to be a bit more pedantic use perfect forwarding (from comment):

```
  void apply_process(A<T> obj, UnaryFunction&& process) {
    data = std::forward<UnaryFunction>(process)(obj);
  }
```

Comment: Should probably perfect-forward the callable: `P&& process`, `std::forward<P>(process)` (or, if it's called more than once, just do the first part).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, sure. I agree. I pass by value to emphasize that "process" should be a small function in principle. (like STL assumes, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: I still think that STL receiving callables by value is a mistake (or a legacy of C++98?). I think some implementations tend to even *copy* it more than once, and call different copies. :/

Comment: I agree. I guess STL was designed without forwarding references and somethings can not be changed now because they depend on copies actually be made. Conceptually, for "pure"-like functions the result should not depend on whether a copy is made or not.